# How to get yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format from "2015-06-26T00:10:00+01:00" in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date-format

**I have stuck in issue in which i have to convert date format is 2015-06-26T00:10:00+01:00 into yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
please give me some idea how to do this?**

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
let startTimeString = "2015-06-26T00:10:00+01:00"
let  startTime = formatter.dateFromString(startTimeString)
print("start time : \(startTime)")
```

and the out put is start time : nil

Answer (score 7):

```
let startTimeString = "2015-06-26T00:10:00+01:00"

// First convert the original formatted date/time to a string:

let deFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
deFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let startTime = deFormatter.dateFromString(startTimeString)
print(startTime!) // 2015-06-25 23:10:00 +0000
// Note that `println` use the `description` method which defaults to UTC.

// Then convert the date/time to the desired formatted string:

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let timeString = formatter.stringFromDate(startTime!)
print(timeString) // 2015-06-25 19:10:00
// Note that `NSDateFormatter` defaults to the local time zone.
```

See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)  )

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this one too?

```
var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
let dateTimePrefix: String = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 5

```
let formatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateTime: String = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
let dateString = "2015-06-26T00:10:00+01:00"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxxx"

if let dateFromString = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" //which format is needed
    let stringFromDate = formatter.string(from: dateFromString)
    print(stringFromDate)
}
```