# I want to convert current Date to simple Date format

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Can anyone please help me converting current date to this format:

> "2017-06-15T05:15:31.158Z".

I need this format only, another format is not acceptable to my backend.

Friend, please help me here.

Comment: show your tried code always

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let timeString = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
print(timeString)
```

[How to get yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format from "2015-06-26T00:10:00+01:00" in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160094/how-to-get-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-format-from-2015-06-26t0010000100-in-swift)

Comment: Hi junaid....i tried but it is printing "2017-07-27 12:18:41"....T and Z is missing